# jQuery - Difference between replaceWith making ajax call or vice versa

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Suppose I want to make an ajax call to the server and use the response to replace a section of existing document content.  Would there be any reason to choose one of these methods over the other?

*Option 1* - make the ajax call, and perform the replaceWith from the error/success functions. Example:

```
$.ajax({
      type      :  'GET',
      url       :  '/some/path/here',
      success   :  function(data) {
        // process data here
        $('#container').replaceWith(processedData);
      }
});
```

*Option 2* -  call replaceWith, passing in a function that makes the ajax call. Example:

```
$("#container").replaceWith(function(){
    var responseData;
    $.ajax({
      type      :  'GET',
      url       :  '/some/path/here',
      success   :  function(data) {
        // process data here
        responseData = processedData;  // 
      }
    });
    return responseData;
});
```

Comment: ProcessedData is never given any value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second one is not an option. When you take the function out;

```
function(){
    var responseData;
    $.ajax({
      type      :  'GET',
      url       :  '/some/path/here',
      success   :  function(data) {
        // process data here
        responseData = processedData;  // 
      }
    });
    return responseData;
}
```

This will return `undefined`. Cause, when the time function runs and returns, `reponseData` is `undefined`. Only, sometime in future, `success` function executes and sets `responseData`. However, your `replaceWith` code has already finished executing.

Go with option 1.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is your only choice, as option 2 would not work as the call would execute asynchronously. This means your function would never return anything.

If you are looking to externalise the processing of the data returned from your AJAX call, just set the `success` parameter as a reference to the function you want to execute:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/some/path/here',
    success: processData
});

function processData(data) {
    // process data here
    $('#container').replaceWith(data);
}
```